# Change position of second letter in TextView to move more up

Tags: java, android, textview

I am implementing some formulas and I have a problem with [subscript](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sub.asp) text in TextView. It goes down a lot.

As you can see at the image the letter R goes way down.

[image]

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brzina_r);
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("U<sub>R</sub>")
```

Is there a way to change position of subscript text to move more up?
I tried using `SpannableStringBuilder` but didn't find any solution.

This is the look I am trying to get.
[image]

Comment: check this ans it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712935/multiple-font-size-for-button-not-working/44713070#44713070

Comment: I tried this, but it is still way down and I cant make it a lot bigger because it needs to be smaller than the first letter.

Comment: You might consider increasing the height of your textView.

Comment: I tried that too. But nothing.

Comment: use two different textviews having Frame Layout as parent you can handle them more precisely